# Printing custom data type in haskell

Tags: haskell

I was trying to learn type classes in haskell and have trouble representing and printing custom data type classes

Here's what I tried, my goal is to print the value.

```
data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green deriving(Show)

instance Eq TrafficLight where
    Red == Red = True
    _ == _ = False

main = do
    print x
    print y
    print z
    where
        x = (TrafficLight Red)
        y = (TrafficLight Red == TrafficLight Red)
        z = (TrafficLight Red == TrafficLight Yellow)
```

I'm getting
`Data constructor not in scope: TrafficLight :: TrafficLight -> t`

Comment: Well, you haven't defined Blue at all. You have only defined Red, Yellow, Green. So it is expected that Blue is undefined. BTW you do not need to prefix the value with its type, this is not an "enum class" à la C++. And you can let the system derive the Eq instance for you.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've tried TrafficLight Red with and without the ( ), I'm getting the error `Data constructor not in scope: TrafficLight :: TrafficLight -> t`

Comment: @jpmarinier oh thank you, so i can straight up use `Red` instead of `TrafficLight Red`

Comment: In fact, the expression `TrafficLight Red` is invalid, as `TrafficLight` is just a *type*, not a constructor.

Comment: In an earlier attempt i use `Stack [1..10]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365706/haskell-reccursive-implementation-for-maybe/68371113#68371113 so, i thought it was necessary now, it makes sense

Comment: Unrelated point: Your implementation of `Eq` is wrong. It isn't reflective `Yellow == Yellow` is false. I bet it breaks some contract.

Comment: @talex yea, I get the logic. i was trying out in case only if red == red is true and others return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green deriving(Show)
```

defines three different things at once:

- A new *type* called `TrafficLight`.
- Three *constructors* for that type, called `Red`, `Yellow` and `Green`. A constructor itself can be seen as an *n*-ary function from the contained data types (in this case there is no contained data, so the constructors are “nullary” – in other words, not functions at all) to the type you're defining. I.e.

  ```
  Red :: TrafficLight
  Yellow :: TrafficLight
  Green :: TrafficLight
  ```

  (In general, e.g. for `data Foo = Quz Int | Ruz Char Bool`, it would be `Quz :: Int -> Foo` and `Ruz :: Char -> Bool -> Foo`.)

  You seem to be confused because in e.g. C++ or Python, constructors are invoked with the same name as the class (and thus type) you're defining, but in Haskell constructors can either be called the same as the type, or different. By convention, if there's just a single constructor it tends to be called the same as the type, if there are multiple constructors they're all called different. For example, if you had defined

  ```
  data TrafficLight'
    = TrafficLight' { redLightOn :: Bool
                    , yellowLightOn :: Bool
                    , greenLightOn :: Bool }
  ```

  then to generate a value corresponding to `Red` in your current data type, you would write `TrafficLight' True False False`.

  An OO analogue to Haskell's multi-constructor types would be an abstract base class with a specific number of child classes, like

  ```py
  class TrafficLight:    # could inherit `abc.ABC` to make it
     pass                # explicitly abstract

  class Red(TrafficLight):
     def __init__(self):
         pass
  class Yellow(TrafficLight):
     def __init__(self):
         pass
  class Green(TrafficLight):
     def __init__(self):
         pass
  ```

  which would allow you to use e.g. `Red()` and get a value that can be used as a value of type `TrafficLight`.
  <sub>(In Python, the typing relationships are of course somewhat meaningless...)</sub>
  <sub>(Yes, I know Python also has Enum types which solve this particular problem better.)</sub>
- A `Show` instance, like you could also write separately

  ```
  instance Show TrafficLight where
    show = ...
  ```

Because `Red`, `Yellow` and `Green` are actually values of type `TrafficLight`, you can simply use them like that in your source file or at the REPL

```
Prelude> data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green deriving(Show)
Prelude> Red
Red
```

You could also add a *local signature* within a bigger expression

```
Prelude> (Red :: TrafficLight, 37)
(Red,37)
```

...but what doesn't make sense is use the name `TrafficLight` directly in value-level code.

Answer (score 4):

`TrafficLight` is name of your type.

`Red`, `Yellow`, `Green` are constructors.

You don't have data constructor with name `TrafficLight`.

FIX:

```
x =  Red
y = (Red == Red)
z = (Red == Yellow)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm having bit of a hard time wrapping head around example like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365706/haskell-reccursive-implementation-for-maybe/68371113#68371113 and this one. if we write `data MyData x = MyData [x]` is MyData the constructor and the type name ?

Comment: You can have type and constructor with same name (they live in different scopes, so it is never create a problem). It is usual practice for types with only one constructor.

Comment: ok, i just did `data Red = Red deriving (Show)
data TrafficLight = TrafficLight Red | LambPost Red deriving(Show)` and now It's getting some what clear.